# how to Construction of Cross Validation Plot using LOOCV

Tags: r

```
loocv <- glm(data_set, tree)$delta[1]
```

haven't received result, error pop up in glm(data_set, tree) : 'family' not recognized

2.
stop("'family' not recognized")
1.
glm(data_set, tree)

Comment: See `?family` for the list of families you are allowed to put in to `glm()`

Comment: how to find the family?

Comment: It's listed in the help page that pops up when you run the code I provided.

Comment: Greetings! Usually it is helpful to provide a minimally reproducible dataset for questions here so people can troubleshoot your problems. One way of doing this is by using the `dput` function. You can find out how to use it here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg

Answer (score 0):

So the syntax for `glm` is as follows:

```
glm(formula, family = gaussian, data, weights, subset,
    na.action, start = NULL, etastart, mustart, offset,
    control = list(…), model = TRUE, method = "glm.fit",
    x = FALSE, y = TRUE, singular.ok = TRUE, contrasts = NULL, …)
```

Note that the second argument to this is family. `tree` is not an acceptable family, the allowed values are:

```
binomial(link = "logit")
gaussian(link = "identity")
Gamma(link = "inverse")
inverse.gaussian(link = "1/mu^2")
poisson(link = "log")
quasi(link = "identity", variance = "constant")
quasibinomial(link = "logit")
quasipoisson(link = "log")
```

Were you trying to fit a tree based model like a CART? If so I recommend using a package like `tree` or `rpart` to fit this to your data.